# Mysql Dividing integer to integer and checking if bigger than 10

Tags: mysql

http://prntscr.com/30rri1

How can I divide Kills to Deaths and see everyone that has a division more than 10?

SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE DIV(Kills/Deaths) > 10

I tried this, but no hope..

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `SELECT * FROM players WHERE Kills/Deaths > 10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simply:

```
SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE Kills/Deaths > 10
```

For integer division you can use `DIV` as an inline operator like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE Kills DIV Deaths > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the div function.

Col1/col2 will do the division no function needed